# Getting the highest value excluding a certain value from a nested object property

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

What I have to do here is quite specific and the iteration logic is beyond me, I'm afraid. Okay... I have an object which looks something like this:

```js
var answers = {
  cat1: {
    q1: {
      "question": "Why?",
      "answer": "No",
      "points": 6
    },
    q2: {
      "question": "Why oh why?",
      "answer": "50%",
      "points": 15
    },
    q3: {
      "question": "Is it true?",
      "answer": "Maybe",
      "points": 9
    }
  },
  cat2: {
    q1: {
      "question": "Hello?",
      "answer": "Hello",
      "points": 0
    },
    q2: {
      "question": "Why me?",
      "answer": "Because",
      "points": 9
    },
    q3: {
      "question": "Is it true?",
      "answer": "Maybe",
      "points": 0
    }
  },
  cat3: {
    q1: {
      "question": "why not?",
      "answer": "I don't know",
      "points": 15
    },
    q2: {
      "question": "What?",
      "answer": "That",
      "points": 9
    },
    q3: {
      "question": "Is it real?",
      "answer": "Nope",
      "points": 6
    }
  }
}
```

For each "category", the property names of which I will not know, I need to find the highest points, *excluding* points of exactly 15 (that is, 15 is a special case, so I would consider 9 the highest out of 0, 9 and 15) for the "q(n)" nested objects in a category.

I want to take each of these high scores and add them together, probably by +=ing a "total" variable.

I feel as though I should be simplifying the object using underscore.js somehow so that I'm left with just `q1: 6` etc, deleting properties with a value of 15, then using underscore's `_.max()` function take the highest points value for each `q(n)` before adding these high scores together.

In the example this would be 9 plus 9 plus 9 (27).

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use a simple `for` loop iterating over the keys of your `Object`, then you can sum up the results.

```
var maxs = {},
      tot = 0;

for (var i in answers) {
    maxs[i] = 0;
    for (var j in answers[i]) {
        if (answers[i][j].points != 15) maxs[i] = Math.max(maxs[i], answers[i][j].points);
        else delete answers[i][j];
        // ^ delete the question if the score is 15
    }
    tot += maxs[i];
}
```

The result will be something like this:

```
maxs
> {
   cat1: 9,
   cat2: 9,
   cat3: 9
}

tot
> 27
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`_.mapObject`](http://underscorejs.org/#mapObject) with a custom iteratee for [`_.max`](http://underscorejs.org/#max) to get the the highest points by category :

```
var maxes = _.mapObject(answers, function (qs) {
    var maxq = _.max(qs, function (q) {
        return (q.points !== 15) ? q.points : -Infinity;
    });

    return maxq.points;
});
```

will output

> {cat1=9, cat2=9, cat3=9}

http://jsfiddle.net/v80z9w2y/ for a demo

[`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) will let you get the total :

```
var sum = _.reduce(maxes, function(memo, num){ return memo + num; }, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v80z9w2y/1/

You can of course combine those two steps if you're only interested in the sum:

```
var sum = _.reduce(answers, function (memo, qs) {
    var maxq = _.max(qs, function(q) {
        return (q.points !== 15) ? q.points : -Infinity;
    });

    return memo + maxq.points;
}, 0);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/v80z9w2y/2/

Comment: Ah, yes I thought I might use _.reduce toward the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version using underscore:

```
    var sum = _.reduce(answers, function(memo, cat){
        return memo + _.max(_.without( _.pluck(cat, 'points'), 15) );
    }, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

This code will work in any modern browser without need for any libraries

```
var categories = [];
for (var cat in answers) {
  categories.push(answers[cat]);
}
var sum = categories.map(function (cat) {
  var highest = 0;
  for (var q in cat) {
    var question = cat[q];
    if (question.points !== 15) {
      highest = Math.max(highest, question.points);
    }
  }
  return highest;
}).reduce(function (prev, current) {
  return prev + current;
}, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer has already been chosen but the question is interesting so here's my attempt:

```
function getTotal(answers){
    return Object.keys(answers).reduce(function(total, cat){
        return total + Math.max.apply(window, 
            Object.keys(answers[cat]).map(function(question){
                return answers[cat][question].points === 15 ? 0 : answers[cat][question].points;
            })
        );
    },0);
}
```

[Demo on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandro_paganotti/8oyfoobz/)